# How to add a legend over each segment in axis environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis

i would like to have in each of segments of the graph, created by the provided example, a text say n=1, n=2,... n=4. I think i would first have to change the scaling, because otherwise I have no space in the leftmost segement (starting the axis at 0 is not an option).

```
\documentclass[letter,12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = left,
    xlabel = $\beta$,
    ylabel = {$E[\pi_B(\beta)]/10^4$}, ] %Below the red parabola is defined \addplot [
    domain=1875/497:4, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red     ] {5*(-(1/3) + 5/x)};

\addplot [
    domain=2500/741:1875/497, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red     ] { 50/3 / x};

\addplot [
    domain=625/196:2500/741, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red   ] { 5*(1/5 + 5/2/x)};

\addplot [
    domain=305/97:625/196, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red ] { 5*(1/3 + 2/x)};

\draw[dashed] (1875/497, 4.4) -- (1875/497,5); \draw[dashed] (2500/741,4.4) -- (2500/741,5); \draw[dashed] (625/196,4.4) -- (625/196,5);

\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may have misunderstood your question. Did you mean something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[letter,12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  plotnode/.style={
     midway,
     sloped,
     above,
     font=\footnotesize,
     node contents={ \pgfmathparse{\numplots - \plotnum} $n = \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}$ } % courtesy of Stefan Pinnow, see comment below
     }
]
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = left,
    xlabel = $\beta$,
    ylabel = {$E[\pi_B(\beta)]/10^4$},
    ]%Below the red parabola is defined

\addplot [
    domain=1875/497:4, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red     ] {5*(-(1/3) + 5/x)}
    node[plotnode];

\addplot [
    domain=2500/741:1875/497, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red     ] { 50/3 / x}
    node[plotnode];

\addplot [
    domain=625/196:2500/741, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red   ] { 5*(1/5 + 5/2/x)}
    node[plotnode];

\addplot [
    domain=305/97:625/196, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red ] { 5*(1/3 + 2/x)}
    node[plotnode];

\draw[dashed] (1875/497, 4.4) -- (1875/497,5);
\draw[dashed] (2500/741, 4.4) -- (2500/741,5);
\draw[dashed] (625/196,4.4) -- (625/196,5);

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Or perhaps this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[letter,12pt,twoside,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  labelnode/.style={font=\footnotesize, above},
  labelline/.style={stealth-stealth,shorten >=0.1pt, shorten <=0.5pt}
]
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = left,
    xlabel = $\beta$,
    ylabel = {$E[\pi_B(\beta)]/10^4$},
    width=10cm,
    height=5cm,
    clip mode=individual
    ]

\addplot [
    domain=1875/497:4, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red     ] {5*(-(1/3) + 5/x)} ;

\addplot [
    domain=2500/741:1875/497, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red     ] { 50/3 / x};

\addplot [
    domain=625/196:2500/741, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red   ] { 5*(1/5 + 5/2/x)};

\addplot [
    domain=305/97:625/196, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red ] { 5*(1/3 + 2/x)};

\coordinate (l) at (rel axis cs:0,1.1);

\draw [labelline] (305/97, 0 |- l) -- node[labelnode]{$n=1$} (625/196, 0 |- l);
\draw [labelline] (625/196, 0 |- l) -- node[labelnode]{$n=2$} (2500/741, 0 |- l);
\draw [labelline] (2500/741, 0 |- l) -- node[labelnode]{$n=3$} (1875/497, 0 |- l);
\draw [labelline] (1875/497, 0 |- l) -- node[above]{$n=4$} (4, 0 |- l);

\draw[dashed] (1875/497, 4.4) -- (1875/497,5);
\draw[dashed] (2500/741, 4.4) -- (2500/741,5);
\draw[dashed] (625/196, 4.4) -- (625/196,5);

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If useless I'll delete.

Comment: You can simplify the first approach by adding `node contents={
                    \pgfmathparse{\numplots - \plotnum}
                $n = \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}$
            },` to the definition of `plotnode` and removing the `{...}` parts of the `node`s.

Comment: Wow, the second solution is absolutely amazing. thank you very much!